# Why do my texture bakes turn pink?

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

I'm trying to link baked texture files to my character. I have been using the *SimpleBake* add-on. My character turns pink as if Blender cannot find my texture files. As far as I can see, my texture files look just fine and well. I browse to them from the image texture node as I should. I even tried baking just one UDIM file hoping that should help. Nope. I've also tried *File* -> *External Data* -> *Find missing files*. Doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

See images attached. Hopefully they can explain my problem.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried *File > External Data > Report missing files*? Maybe there is an HDRI missing?

Comment: The tutorial I am following does not use HDRI. World colour is set to white.

Comment: Ah ok. And what reports Blender when you use File > External Data > ...*? It should tell you if files are missing and where to find them.

Comment: Yes, since I have been trying this over and over again I have a number of files from old versions reported missing. I have now retrieved them from my trashcan. I no longer get reports about missing files. Still, my character is pink.

Comment: Have you checked if the images are present in the image editor (texture paint workspace)? The thumbnails are cached and the image can still be missing. But you should see images if you select them from the drop-down menu. In the side panel (key N) you can see the file path. Maybe it's because of the UDIMs? Is the *Tiled* option checked in the image settings? The files need a number in their filename, something like *"skin normal.1001.png"*.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you, but as far as I can see things are correct there. It is basically the same drop down menu as in the layout workspace. However it says "Can't load image". in the texture paint workspace.

Comment: Just for trouble shooting, I tried a random texture from Polyhaven (a fabric texture). It works fine. Thus, the problem is obviously about my UDIMS and or my bakes. I still don't understand why since there is nothing wrong wit the .png from my bakes (as far as I can see).

Comment: The problem is definitely related to the UDIM-tiles. When I changes the Image texture nodes from UDIM to Single, it works. Not really a solution though, since there is no point in using UDIMs with texture nodes set to single.

Comment: Yes, looks like it's the UDIMs that cause the trouble. I tried to clarify my previous comment in this comment but it's too long and there is already a suggestion to use the chat instead of the comment section. Too bad that the chat requires 50 reputations and you're 19 reps too short. It doesn't help. So I finally posted the explanation as an answer and hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is something wrong with UDIMs as already mentioned in the comments. It's either a wrong filename, a wrong folder, wrong tile numbers, or wrong settings. I still wonder why you no longer get messages about missing files when you select the menu entry *File > External Data > Report Missing Files* of the main menu. To track down the error, here are two examples, one working and one with incorrect file names.

**Here is a working UDIM example and a checklist.**

- in the *Image Editor* **(1)**, select the image **(2)** and check if the images are loaded and shown **(3)**
- in the side panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) **(4)** on the *Image* tab you will find the filename of the image. *Source* should be `UDIM Tiles` and in the filename, there should be a `<UDIM>` part. The UIDM tile numbers are shown below. The default values start at 1001.
- in the file browser **(5)** check if the files are in the correct folder and have the correct names. Here the `<UDIM>` part in the filename must be replaced by the tile numbers, e.g. "primitives diffuse.`1001`.png", "primitives diffuse.`1002`.png", and so on.
- in the *Shader Editor*, check if the *Image Texture* node **(6)** has set the source option to `UDIM Tiles` for the given UDIM image texture.
  [image: screenshot everything is good]

**Here is an example of broken filenames.**

The tile numbers in filenames are incorrect **(1)**. In consequence,

- **(2)** you still see the cached icon of the image. But there is an error message *"Can't Load Image"* under the filename and the images are not loaded and not shown.
- **(3)** The models are pink and
- **(4)** there should be a warning in the *Info* view after you run the *File > External Data > Report Missing Files* command. The command *... > Find Missing Files* should also report the missing files if they cannot be found in the selected folder.

[image: screenshot wrong filename]